# rails allow non users edit own profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I've got a site which I created in Rails 3.0 with devise & cancan installed. This application holds a list of just over 4000 people in which members can view. Very few of the people in the database are members.

Is there a way to allow the 4000 people access to update only their profile without having to make them a user?

My current thinking is that I will have three roles (admin, member and updater). The updater role will only have access to their profile and that's it. I will restrict this using cancan.

Is this the best way to do this?
I could randomly generate a password and email out a link to edit their profile in an email, when they click on it my program could ask for their login details and away they go. I was just thinking if their was a better way of doing this without the need to generate so many users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column to your profile model with a randomly generated password, then have a link to edit the profile email that password to the email address on file to edit.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  def generate_edit_key!
    self.edit_key = rand(9999999999)
    save
  end
end

class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def request_edit_key
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    @proifle.generate_edit_key!
    ProfileMailer.edit_profile_request(@profile).deliver
    redirect_to @profile, :notice => 'Mail sent to profile owner'
  end
  def edit
    if current_user
      @profile = current_user.profile
    else
      @profile = Profile.find_by_id_and_edit_key(params[:id], params[:edit_key])
    end
  end
end

class ProfileMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def edit_profile_request(profile)
    mail(:to => profile.email,
         :subject => 'Edit your profile',
         :body => "<%= link_to 'Click to edit' edit_profile_url(profile, :edit_key => profile.edit_key) %> If you didn't request this, please ignore.")
end
```

Comment: I had to turn off devise authentication checking for edit and update, is there a way around doing this without overriding authenticate_user!? Here is the line I currently use:
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:edit, :update]

Comment: @map7 You could create a special controller and action just for doing the edit, and not protect that one.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make them users, then use a token system to grant them temporary access to do the thing.

```
link_to 'Let me update this profile', token_path(:id = @profile.id, :method => :post)

class TokensController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    if @profile.send_token!
      redirect_to profile_path(@profile), :notice => 'A token has been sent'
    else
      redirect_to profile_path(@profile), :error => 'A token could not be sent'
    end
  end
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tokens
  def send_token!
    token = self.tokens.create()
    TokenMailer.update_profile(token).deliver
  end
end

class Token < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  before_save :generate_key, set_expiration
  def generate_key
    self.key = rand(999999999999)
  end
  def set_expiration
    self.expires_at = 1.day.from_now
  end
  def expired?
    expires_at > Time.now
  end
end

class TokenMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def update_profile(token)
    mail(:to => token.profile.email,
         :subject => 'Edit your profile',
         :body => "<%= link_to 'Click to edit' edit_profile_url(token.profile, :key => token.key) %>")
  end
end

class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    if params[:key]
      token = Token.find_by_key(params[:key])
      if token.expired?
        redirect_to root_url, :message => 'Token Expired'
      else
        @profile = token.profile
      end
    elsif current_user
      @profile = current_user.profiles.detect{|p| p.id == params[:id] }
    else
      redirect_to root_url, :message => 'Not allowed'
    end
  end
end
```